# Funcion para sumar con evento OnClick en Javascript en input

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

estoy haciendo una "calculadora" donde tenga que sumar 2 valores ingresados en un input y se retorne el valor sumado en un 3er input, cuando pruebo el código realizado, con un console.log si suma dentro de la consola, sin embargo, al hacerle click al boton, no muestra el valor del resultado de la suma dentro del input. Que me falta?? Gracias por la ayuda

```
window.calculateSumListener = function calculateSumListener() {
    //Devuelve el valor del input #firstNumber
    var stringA = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    //Devuelve el valor del input #secondNumber
    var stringB = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

    let result = parseInt(stringA) + parseInt(stringB);

    document.getElementById("resultNumber").innerHTML = result;
};
```

El HTML que viene en el ejercicio y al que hay que aplicarle la funcion con eventos es el siguiente.

```
<body>
        <input id="firstNumber" type="text" value="" /> + <input id="secondNumber" type="text" value="" /> =
        <input id="resultNumber" type="text" value="0" />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateSumListener();" />
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("resultNumber").innerHTML = result;` te falta la **t**

Comment: gracias @hawks lo correji sin embargo, no era eso lo que ocasiona que no se muestre el resultado

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que estas usando la propiedad `innerHTML` para setear el valor de un `input`.

Tienes que usar `value` para setear el valor de un `input, select, textarea`. Ya que estos elementos no pueden tener html por eso no funciona `innerHTML`.

```js
window.calculateSumListener = function calculateSumListener() {
    //Devuelve el valor del input #firstNumber
    var stringA = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    //Devuelve el valor del input #secondNumber
    var stringB = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;

    let result = parseInt(stringA) + parseInt(stringB);

    document.getElementById("resultNumber").value = result;
};
```

```html
        <input id="firstNumber" type="text" value="" /> + <input id="secondNumber" type="text" value="" /> =
        <input id="resultNumber" type="text" value="0" />
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculateSumListener();" />
        <script src="index.js"></script>
```